# Wrapping my head around TPL DataFlow

Tags: c#, wcf, task-parallel-library, simple-injector, tpl-dataflow

I have a windows service (using `Topshelf`) which hosts a `WCF` service (created using `SimpleInjectorServiceHost`) and also spins up threads (using `Task.Run`).

The idea is to:

- `WCF` service receives commands
- post those commands to `BufferBlock<T>`. The service needs this `BufferBlock<T>` injected into its constructor
- threads are supposed to be `TransformBlock<T>`'s which will do the required action and return result
- this result needs to be read back by the `WCF` service method and returned back to the caller

I am just starting with TPL Dataflow so maybe my understanding of action blocks is totally wrong

I spin the threads in the windows service OnStart method

```
for(var i = 0, i < Environment.ProcessorCount, ++i)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var scope = Bootstrapper.BeginScope())
        {
            var threadHost = Bootstrapper.GetInstance<IThreadHost>();
            threadHost.DoWork(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
    }, _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
};
```

`Bootstrapper.BeginScope` simply abstracts away SimpleInjector's `_container.BeginLifetimeScope()` method

`IThreadHost`/`ThreadHost` is a simple interface/class that has methods for each command type. `DoWork` is supposed to wait on the `BufferBlock` and process each item once available.

The `WCF` service is started using

```
if (_serviceHost != null)
{
    _serviceHost.Close();
}
_serviceHost = Bootstrapper.CreateServiceHost(typeof(NodeService));
_serviceHost.Open();
```

`Bootstrapper.CreateServiceHost` simply abstracts away `new SimpleInjectorServiceHost(_container, serviceType)`.

Q: Should the `BufferBlock<T>` be a singleton registered with `SimpleInjector`?

Q: How to set `DoWork` of each `threadHost` as the `TransformBlock<T>` and link to the `BufferBlock<T>`?

Q: How do I get output of the `TransformBlock<T>` in my `WCF` service method? `WCF` service methods writes the command to `BufferBlock<T>` and then needs to wait for the output somehow?

Answer (score 3):

I think you a little bit over-complicating this. You really do not need a threads for your `TransformBlock` workers - each block in TPL DataFlow already has a corresponding task. If you want, you can [optimize it's usage for your needs with options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx#behavior).

What you got here in your solution is a general [`Producer/Consumer` pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601.aspx), which can be done much more easily with TPL DataFlow. So the answer for your first question:

> Q: Should the BufferBlock be a singleton registered with SimpleInjector?

Yes, either `BufferBlock` and `TransformBlock` should be singletons, but it depends on the answer for third question

As I said already, you really don't need threads with `TPL` and `TPL DataFlow`, so second question is easy to answer too:

> Q: How to set DoWork of each threadHost as the TransformBlock and link
>   to the BufferBlock?

You should use no threads in your solution and direct linking the `TransformBlock` to the `BufferBlock`

As for third question, here is the interesting part, because the answer is:

> Q: How do I get output of the TransformBlock in my WCF service method?
>   WCF service methods writes the command to BufferBlock and then needs
>   to wait for the output somehow?

It depends.

Main idea of data processing with TPL DataFlow is that it is asynchronous, and you can't be definitely sure that what you have on exit of the `TransformBlock` is the result exactly yours request - there could be other data being transformed with other requests, and simply polling the output with `OutputAvailableAsync()` could be quite inefficient method for your solution.

In this case you should create some kind of dictionary for processing results so you can easily get information, is your request done or not. In this case of implementation you can return the id for request, and introduce another service method for getting the results by that id.

Another approach is incapsulate data flow into one helper class, which will contains it's own copy of `BufferBlock` and `TransformBlock`, and in this case you can create a `async` method using polling, as in linked example. Please note that in this case of implementation you really don't need the TPL DataFlow at all.